# DataTables how to call data.json properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, datatables

My data for a DataTable is currently located at the bottom of my `app.js` and looks something like this:

```
var data = {
"things": [
{
"date": {
    "display": "April 15, 2011",
    "date_order": "1"
},
"place": "Chicago, auto parts yard"
]
...
};
```

I am calling the data at the top of my `app.js` like this:

```
var table =  $('#table').DataTable({
      "data": data.things,
      "columnDefs": [
        { "type": "num", "targets": 1 },
        { "type": "num", "targets": 3 }
      ],
      "columns": []
...
```

I've followed [this](http://live.datatables.net/bihawepu/2098/edit) pretty closely, and it's working for me.

Obviously, it's bad practice to keep your data inside your `app.js`. But when I move my data to a `data.json` file inside a `data` folder, I can't seem to call it. Would calling the data then look something like this:

```
var table =  $('#table').DataTable({
          "data": "../data.json",
...
```

because that seems to not be working, unless I'm doing it horribly wrong. What would be the proper syntax for that? FWIW, my `app.js` is inside `js/src` and my `data.json` is inside a `data` folder which is at the same level as my `js` folder.

Comment: what is root of your application or where are you calling the `app.js` you need to provide path relative to the document root, and include `data` folder in your path too

Comment: I think, you have to take a look at this: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: Doesn't the data option expect an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to load data from external data source via Ajax.

If your directory structure is:

```
/
├── js/
│   └── app.js
└── data/
    └── data.json
```

Then use the code below:

```
var table =  $('#table').DataTable({
      // ... skipped ...
      "ajax": {
         "url": "../data/data.json",
         "dataSrc": "things"
      }
});
```

Comment: I've done this but am getting an ["invalid JSON"](http://datatables.net/tn/1) response. I then put my json into [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to make sure it was valid; there were errors so I pasted the correctly formatted json into my `data.json` and retried -- still getting the invalid JSON response.